# UIAlertController freezes the UI when presented after pausing the layer animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimationtransition

In a `ViewController`, I am performing a transition animation on a view. On a button action, the transition animation is **paused by setting the layer speed equals to zero**.

But, when the alert is presented over the screen after pausing the animation, the UI freezes and when I move the app from foreground to background and then again to foreground after some time, the alert action starts working. Does anybody have an idea of this issue?

```
func pauseLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}
```

Code for animation:

```
UIView.transition(with: self.rotatingView, duration: 1.0, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft], animations: {
        }) { (true) in
        //    print("completed")
        }
```

Comment: put transition animation code as well

Comment: @SGDev check the edited question